# UIGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch

Not sure what i'm doing wrong but here's a simplified example:

```
@interface Test : NSObject<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    UIView *_someParentView;
    UIView *_someChildView;
}
- (id)initWithParentView:(UIView *)parentView;
@end

@implementation Test

- (id)initWithParentView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _someParentView = parentView;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addSubViewsWhenReady
{
    _someChildView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    _someChildView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [_someChildView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_someParentView addSubview:_someChildView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
    [_someChildView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"handle the single tap");
}

@end
```

The output: "handle the single tap" is never logged. Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `_someParentView` added as a subview somewhere?

Comment: I'm guessing that the parent view gets added in the view controller.  It would be good to show how this code gets called from your view controller.

Comment: ssantos: Yes, _parentView is added as a subview in a view controller. Jeff Wolski: (sorry for the pseudo code) UIView *someContanier = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:xxx]; [[test alloc] initWithParentView:someContainer]; [self.view addSubView:someContainer];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the target like you are doing:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
```

is your problem. If "self" here is a UIViewController, it will work.

i.e.

```
@interface Test : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    UIView *_someParentView;
    UIView *_someChildView;
}
- (id)initWithParentView:(UIView *)parentView;
@end

@implementation Test

- (id)initWithParentView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _someParentView = parentView;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addSubViewsWhenReady
{
    _someChildView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    _someChildView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [_someChildView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_someParentView addSubview:_someChildView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
    [_someChildView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer    {
    NSLog(@"handle the single tap");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your definition of `handleSingleTap:` to

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"handle the single tap");
}
```

---

From the `UIGestureRecognizer` docs:

> A gesture recognizer has one or more target-action pairs associated with it. If there are multiple target-action pairs, they are discrete, and not cumulative. Recognition of a gesture results in the dispatch of an action message to a target for each of those pairs. **The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following signatures**:
>
> `- (void)handleGesture;`
>
> `- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;`

Comment: This will make no difference. The argument types are not part of a signature so wether you use `id` or `UIGestureRecognizer` or `UITapGestureRecognizer`, the signature will still be `handleSingleTap:`.